# Problems with 'Publish Web Site' on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, compilation, publishing

Recently I've upgraded from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010, however I'm having various problems when uploading my compiled web site to the live area. I'm doing exactly the same as I would have done with Visual Studio 2008, however, now I receive errors such as:

```
{filename}.aspx is not a pre-compiled file

masterpage.master does not exist
```

All these errors don't make sense. Has anyone encountered these problems before, and was a solution ever found?

Comment: Is the virtual directory on your server correct? e.g. it is now using Framework 4.0?

Comment: Nothing has changed apart from the software on my machine. I assume I can still compile my .net 2.0 & 3.5 websites successfully on Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: is it the exception "The file 'foo.aspx' has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested'." ? Can you post the exact wording apart from the filename?

Comment: @p.campbell I can confirm that is exactly the error I am getting. However it makes no sense as the files are in fact pre-compiled. Cheers.

Comment: I've just tried publishing again, and I'm receiving this error:
'The file '/Admin/MasterPage.master' does not exist.'

Now, obviously '/Admin/MasterPage.master' doesn't technically exist as its compiled into the bin folder, so why would I get this message? :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try run the `Clean Solution` command from the Build menu on your solution. 
  [image]
- Try diagnosing by publishing to a brand new IIS location. Perhaps there are files from your VS2008 build that aren't being overwritten by your VS2010 build.
- Are all the files present in the bin directory as you'd expect?
- Is there an `PrecompiledAppConfig.config` file in the root?

Comment: The only one of those points I'm unsure about is a 'Clean Solution'. How would I run this command in VS2010? Thanks.

Comment: Thats strange as 'Clean Solution' doesn't appear on my VS2010 :S http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/7664/82991958.jpg . I'm running version 10.0.30319.1

Answer (score 1):

You can run the Clean command by selecting Build -> Batch Build.  You will see the options Build, Rebuild, and Clean in the dialog box.

The web site does not have to be created in IIS in order to use the Batch Build dialog.

Hope this helps,
Rick

Answer (score 0):

you probably have not created an application or virtual directory on your server.

use IIS Manager to create it